# How many positive integers from set $\{1,2...,10^{30}\}$ can't be represented as 2nd, 3rd, or 5th power of some positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

An interesting problem I ran across. My guess is that it can be solved somehow using **inclusion-exclusion principle**. It would be a fun thing to learn how to do this, so I could use that knowledge in solving some other problems. Tried searching the internet, but didn't find any tutorial or similar problem like this one. I hope that this post will help someone in the future who needs to solve this type of problems.

So, it goes like:

> How many positive integers from set $\{1,2...,10^{30}\}$ can't be represented as 2nd, 3rd, or 5th power of some positive integer?

Comment: You might also indicate, with only three types of exclusions, that inclusion-exclusion is also a valid way to proceed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, totally forgot about that, +1

Comment: There, indicated.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion is the way to go: the number of numbers that _can_ be so represetned is (squares + cubes + fifth powers) - (sixth powers + tenth powers + fifteenth powers) + (thirtieth powers).

Comment: @TonyK it's not just powers of $10$, so you have to permutate beyond $30$ to cater for e.g. $2^{31}$.

Comment: @RobertFrost: No you don't. First you underthought this, now you are overthinking it. Several correct responses have been posted, and you should try to understand them.

Comment: ... now I think you need to un-remove the generating function suggestion (Because everyone went with incl-excl and I want to see a generating function solution that is less horrible than the first one to come off the top of my head...)

Comment: @TonyK yeah you're right. I was watching Wales beat Belgium. GET IN!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $10^{30}=(10^{15})^2=(10^{10})^3=(10^{6})^5=(10^5)^6=(10^3)^{10}=(10^2)^{15}$.

Thus, the number of square is $10^{15}$, the number of cubes is $10^{10}$, the number of 5-th power is $10^6$, the number of 6-th power is $10^5$, the number of 10-th power is $10^3$, the number of 15-th power is $10^2$, and the number of 30-th power is $10$.

Thus, there are $10^{30}-10^{15}-10^{10}-10^6+10^5+10^3+10^2-10$ numbers cannot be represented as 2-nd, 3rd, or 5-th powers.

Comment: Well, what *about* $2^{31}$?

Comment: I don't think it is trickier.  Say 2^40... that was counted as a square (1048576^2).  It was counted as a quint.  (256^5).  And as a 10th power, (16^10).  So it was properly include excluded and included.

Comment: So far as I can tell 2^31 is neither square, cube, nor quint and was never counted and is ... just fine.

Comment: Sorry careless of me, how about $2^{34}$?

Comment: @RobertFrost: $2^{34}$ is counted once as the square of $2^{17}$, and never again as a cube or quint. Sounds right to me...

Comment: @Micah sorry still being careless. Watching telly! But all powers of $2$ up to $2^{99}$? And powers of $3$ up to $3^{62}$...

Comment: Try $2^{62}$ for size!

Comment: @RobertFrost: You appear to be confusing numbers of the form $2^n$ (which are more or less irrelevant to this question) with numbers of the form $n^2$ (which are highly relevant). In fact your original answer would have been very nearly correct if the question had been about powers of 2,3,5 rather than 2nd, 3rd, 5th powers.

Comment: @Micah see previous comment for relevance of $2^n$. X

Comment: Sorry I'm being really daft here as usual but I do have a point! Is $2^{64}$ excluded from the double-counting? There's double-counting of some powers greater than $30$ that need accounting for.

Comment: $2^{64}$ is not excluded from double counting as $2^{64} =4294967296^2$ and was thus counted.  We aren't simply counting the $x^n; n \le 30$ we are counting the $x^{kn}= (x^k)^n; kn > 30; n \le 30$.  This is *not* a problem.

Comment: Powers of 2 up to $2^{99}$.  Yes we *are* doing all those relevant.  $2^{99} = [2^{33}]^3$ and is counted.  $2^{98} = [2^{49}]^2$ and is counted.  $2^{97}$ not a square, cube or quint and is not counted.  $2^{96} = [2^{48}]^2 = [2^{32}]^3$ and is double counted.  Etcetera!  It is *not* a problem.  We took it into account!

Comment: If $x^{n}; n > 30$ needs acounting for then k=2, 3,5 |n and we took it into account with $[x^{n/k}]^k$.  No problems.

Comment: Sorry guys I was being daft last night... I was permutating the ways of arriving at some power but the orders don't matter because multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

There are $10^{15}$ squares.

There are $10^{10}$ cubes.

There are $10^6$ quints.

There are $10^5$ powers to the 6 which are both squares and cubes.

There are $10^3$ powers to the 10 which are both squares and quints.

There are $10^2$ powers to the 15 which are both cubes and quints.

And there are $10$ powers to the 30 which are all three.

Apply Exclusion/Inclusion.

Total that cant be are ALL numbers - (ALL squares,cubes, and quints) + (Those that can be two of the property as these were double counted) - (those that are all three as these were triple counted).

So answer is $10^{30} - (10^{15}+10^{10} + 10^6)+(10^5+10^3+10^2) - 10$